# SQL Update multiple lines from query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have written 2 queries and I need to look at combining them, into what I think would have to be a cursor. The first query looks like this-

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = '12-July-2014'

SELECT  Date AS SaturdayDate
          , DayOfWeek

 FROM (
SELECT DATE
          , DATENAME(DW,DATE) as DayOfWeek
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS rownum
     FROM tblCalender
     WHERE DATENAME(DW,DATE) = 'Saturday'
          AND Date > @Date
          ) AS t
          WHERE t.rownum % 4 = 0
                AND DATEPART(YEAR, Date) = DATEPART(Year, GETDATE())
```

returns every 4th Saturday for the rest of the year past the 12th July -

```
SaturdayDate            |DayOfWeek
2014-08-09 00:00:00.000 |Saturday
2014-09-06 00:00:00.000 |Saturday
2014-10-04 00:00:00.000 |Saturday
2014-11-01 00:00:00.000 |Saturday
2014-11-29 00:00:00.000 |Saturday
2014-12-27 00:00:00.000 |Saturday
```

This is perfect for what I need, then i need to  run an update query using the result of the above as the `@SaturdayDate` parameter (need it to cycle through and update every record)

```
UPDATE    dbo.tblStaffRota
SET              StartTime = '11:00:00'
WHERE     (EmployeeID IN ('JJJ','HSW', 'GPH', 'DVD')) 
                AND (StartTime = '10:30:00')            
                AND (Date BETWEEN @SaturdayDate - 6 AND @SaturdayDate)
```

So the update query will cycle through the result of the first query updating each date with the new start time, not sure how to progress with this and all the answers I've found haven't quiet helped. Hopefully this is clear enough. Thanks

*additional note - The update needs to look at the days in the previous week to each saturday that appears and change whatever the start time is.

Sample of tables being used. 
[image]

Based on this the update would change the start time on the 18th and 19th if the Saturday was in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need something like (Note: below script have not been tested) ..

**Modified** based on posted sample data:

```
    DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = '12-July-2014'


UPDATE    STAFFROTA
SET              StartTime = '11:00:00'
FROM dbo.tblStaffRota STAFFROTA 
    INNER JOIN
    (
            SELECT DATEADD(d, -6, Date) AS SaturdayDateStart,  Date AS SaturdayDateEnd
                  , DayOfWeek
        FROM (
        SELECT DATE
                  , DATENAME(DW,DATE) as DayOfWeek
                  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS rownum
             FROM tblCalender
             WHERE DATENAME(DW,DATE) = 'Saturday'
                  AND Date > @Date
                  ) AS t
                  WHERE t.rownum % 4 = 0
                        AND DATEPART(YEAR, Date) = DATEPART(Year, GETDATE())

    ) SAT
    ON STARFFROTA.[Date] BETWEEN SAT.SaturdayDateStart AND SAT.SaturdayDateEnd
WHERE     (STARFFROTA.EmployeeID IN ('JJJ','HSW', 'GPH', 'DVD')) 
                AND (STARFFROTA.StartTime = '10:30:00')
```

Comment: Not quiet getting me where i need to be, the update query needs to update the proceeding days where the employee starts at 10:30. So if they are working that Saturday, then the days need to have the start time changed.

Comment: Can you post some sample data of the two tables `tblStaffRota` and `tblCalender`

Comment: @Gavlaaa .. Modified code based on your sample data. I believe this is what you require.